# Global error handling for spring standalone application

Tags: java, spring, exception, uncaught-exception, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I have a standalone spring application where one of my bean implementing `UncaughtExceptionHandler` and in main method calling `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler`.
Is there any spring support for global error handling, I found a few options for spring MVC but not for Non-MVC / standalone.

Comment: There is non provided for non-mvc application. . if it is standand alone application how you want to handle the error very specific. it is not probably like redirecting to standard error page. you may to device your own approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring does not support global exception handler for standalone / non-mvc. [As explained here](http://emma.pomogi-mne.com/handling-exception-in-spring-standalone-application-stack-overflow-7550454053/) you may need to implement it by defining jointpoint and pointcuts and enable pointcut for any "*Exception".